# Make element always at center of element in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some center navigation that has always need to be in center, but that is not problem, the problem i have with some element that has to be always right of that element, how to add that this is what i have for now, it goes in accordian head

[image]

Here is boostrap 3 code

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title text-right">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Click Me
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
```

What i need is something like this

[image]

The problem is that i dont know how many icons i would have, and they have always need to be at center of panel, and click me need to be at right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/sJWxG/embedded/result/), it is not very complicated. All you have to do is to set a default bootstrap accordion and set text-center insted of text-right. In this way if you place your icons they will be always aligned to center and after that you will use a `<p style="float: right;">Click Me</p>` in order to place your `Click Me` text in the right.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/sJWxG/) is the code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title text-center">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/15x15">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/15x15">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/15x15">
                    <p style="float: right">Click me</p>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                DEMO TEXT HERE.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, i used 3 icons in this example, but you can add as many as you want and they all will be center aligned.